# Get Custom Post types data from the API

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api

I'm new to the `wp-api`. I'm trying to fetch some data that is being generated by a plugin.
in my case is a booking plugin named `Hotelier`. I'v understood that from version 2 of the api you need to specify the `show_in_rest = true`.

I'v followed this [**Article**](https://scottbolinger.com/custom-post-types-wp-api-v2/), but with no luck after trying to add the code to functions.php and even create a simple plugin.

1. Do I need to add the code from the article in `function.php` or register a new `plugin`
2. the Autor of the plugin mentioned the data is stored in `meta boxes` does it make any difference?

any tips here please, cheers to all

```
add_action( ‘init’, ‘my_custom_post_type_rest_support’, 25 );

function my_custom_post_type_rest_support() {

global $wp_post_types;

//be sure to set this to the name of your post type!
$post_type_name = ‘rooms’;

if( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type_name ] ) ) {

$wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->show_in_rest = true;
// Optionally customize the rest_base or controller class
$wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_base = $post_type_name;
$wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_controller_class = ‘WP_REST_Posts_Controller’;

}

}
```

Comment: Double-check your quotation marks. The ones you posted here are smart quotes that won't work - you need straight `'` quotes. Also double-check your CPT to see whether it is really named `rooms` plural, or if it might be `room` singular. They vary but best practice is to register them as singular, so that could also be affecting it.

Comment: @WebElaine Wow you are Awesome havn't noticed that works like a charm thank you so much really appreciate

Comment: @WebElaine one thing that is missing is those `meta boxes` info. do I need to do something else in order to access them?

Comment: Yes, postmeta isn't available by default. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227506/how-to-get-custom-post-meta-using-rest-api

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks again saved the day totally appreciate the quick reply and Awesome Help :)